# Expander in DataGrid (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, datagrid, silverlight-toolkit, expander

I have a DataGrid and I need to add an Expander control dynamically to group few rows based on some conditions... Can anyone help me in this... I am completely new to Silverlight :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I have created a separate column for the expander and managed to display it when my condition is satisfied. It is not dynamic though, but solved the purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically--not sure what you want.  I've done expanders statically.  My two cents:  keep it simple and don't try and do too much.  If by dynamically you are taking about Master/Details data gridview, that can be done by XAML and loading the gridview with an ObservableCollection class (search the net).  Also search for PagedCollectionView and .Visibility properties for controls.  If you want to add controls to a StackPanel, dynamically, search the net for .Children.Remove methods.

Good luck, but as a beginner you are probably trying to do too much IMO.